# Javafx: How to convert combobox strings to double

Tags: java, javafx

I am looking for a solution to convert Strings that I get from a combobox to double.

I am pretty new to JavaFX and trying to convert an old swing project to fx.

In Swing I have something like this:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    String stringPrice = jTextFieldPrice.getText();

    try {
        double size= nf.parse(jComboboxSize.getItemAt(jComboboxSize.getSelectedIndex()).toString()).doubleValue();          
        double price= nf.parse(stringPrice).doubleValue();
        double newPrice= price * size;
...
```

And my FX code so far

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> bottleSize;
@FXML
private TextField txfBottlePrice;

ObservableList<String> bottleList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    "0,187", 
    "0,25", 
    "0,375", 
    "0,5", 
    "0,62", 
    "0,7", 
    "0,75", 
    "0,8", 
    "1", 
    "1,5" 
);

....
....
   String sPrice = txfBottlePrice.getText();

    try {
         double dSize = Double.parseDouble(bottleSize.getValue());
         double dPrice = Double.parseDouble(sPrice);
         double newPrice = dPrice * dSize;

         txfPriceLiter.setText(Double.toString(newPrice));

    }catch ( NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
    }
```

But ... it's not working.

Comment: Why not just use a `ComboBox<Double>`?

Comment: This would be a solution in general, but not for me, because useability-wise I have to use numbers that are comma seperated, based on the localization. 

And the ComboBox<Double> would only accept an ObserverList<Double> and so the numbers had to be "0.187", and not "0,187".

Comment: So use a format object to convert the values and a cell factory to display them as you want them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! 
I was confused, because at first I tried my old NumberFormat code, but NumberFormat was unknown and Netbeans didn't want to import it. So I thought it's not available in JavaFX. 
But after I pasted the code in, the it recognized it somehow and imported the packages.

Now it's working.

```
 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);


    try {
        double dSize = nf.parse(bottleSize.getValue()).doubleValue();
        double dPrice = nf.parse(txfBottlePrice.getText()).doubleValue();
        double newPrice = dPrice * dSize;
        txfPriceLiter.setText(nf.format(newPrice));
    } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Great it worked. Please consider upvote and accept of my previous answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display comma (,) you may consider converting , to . before parsing.

```
double dSize = Double.parseDouble(bottleSize.getValue().replace(",","."));
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that your code uses input data, which are not in a double compatible format. Instead of a `.,..` format they must be use a dot `.` in between numeric parts. Try this:

```
ObservableList<String> bottleList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    "0.187", 
    "0.25", 
    "0.375", 
    "0.5", 
    "0.62", 
    "0.7", 
    "0.75", 
    "0.8", 
    "1", 
    "1.5" 
);
```

Comment: Damn. Okay. Yeah but in EU you're using a comma and not a dot in double and float numbers. Do you know any other methods to convert comma seperated numbers?

Comment: This is true for most European countries and for visual representation of the data points. Yet, when doing math or computations you have to use a "dot" notation. See also here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

If your `ComboBox` is representing numbers, it should be a `ComboBox<Double>`. Use a `NumberFormat` to convert your strings to the values to be stored in the combo box, and wrap it in a `StringConverter` for the combo box.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;
import javafx.util.converter.FormatStringConverter;

public class ComboBoxDoubleDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        List<String> inputData = Arrays.asList(
                "0,187", 
                "0,25", 
                "0,375", 
                "0,5", 
                "0,62", 
                "0,7", 
                "0,75", 
                "0,8", 
                "1", 
                "1,5" 
            );
        ComboBox<Double> bottleSize = new ComboBox<>();
        NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);

        StringConverter<Double> converter = new FormatStringConverter<>(format);

        bottleSize.getItems().addAll(
                inputData.stream().map(converter::fromString).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        // or, depending on your requirements, just do

//      bottleSize.getItems().addAll(
//            0.187d, 0.25d, 0.375d, 0.5d, 0.62d, 0.7d, 0.75d, 0.8d, 1d, 1.5d
//        );


        bottleSize.setConverter(new FormatStringConverter<Double>(format));
        bottleSize.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

        TextField txfBottlePrice = new TextField();
        txfBottlePrice.setEditable(false);
        txfBottlePrice.textProperty().bind(bottleSize.valueProperty().asString(Locale.GERMANY, "%.3f"));

        VBox root = new VBox(10, bottleSize, txfBottlePrice);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 350, 150));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```